# What's this F#m8b12b#8 chord?

Tags: chords, chord-theory

I often see this image in VK, OK and Facebook. I can't understand this **F#m8b12b#8** chord! I know it's a taunt of a kind but does it really exist and what notes are those and how to play it on Guitar and Keyboard?

[image]

Comment: It is non-sense, this chord doesn't exist.

Comment: Be interested to hear what it translates to, but sadly, don't think it's playable on this planet.

Comment: Note: the keyboardist on this picture is Jordan Rudess, who is mostly known for being the keyboardist of Dream Theater, a progressive metal band. This picture is just a meme reference to Jordan Rudess' tendency to play complicated songs.

Comment: Yeh, i'm familiar woth his work in Dream Theatre.

Comment: It's a really very basic chord. Jordan can play it with his eyes closed!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, as said in my comment, this is a joke and that chord doesn't exist. But here's why:

1. `F#m8` doesn't make sense because `8` is the octave, so it doesn't add anything to the chord.
2. `b12` doesn't exist; the `12` is equivalent to the fifth, which is a basic chord tone, so if it should be flat, it should be a `b5`; however, this contradicts the F#m chord, which as a perfect fifth; there can only be one fifth; enharmonically, the `b5` could be a `#4` (`#11`), so if you wanted to add that note, it should be a `#4` (`#11`). Note, however, that this tension is very uncommon in a minor chord.
3. `b#8` is non-sense; is it flat or sharp or none of the two? Whatever it is, it is also non-sense because, as mentioned above, `8` is just the octave, and in a chord in doesn't make sense to alter the octave. If you want a chord tone a half step lower than the octave, then it's a major seventh; a half step up from the octave, it would be a `b9`;

Comment: In it just a funny way to write F#m?
http://www.scales-chords.com/chord/F%23m8b12b%238 (I don't know how accurate is this tool)

Comment: It's not F#m, as he said there is a flat 5th (or a sharp 4th)...

Comment: Honestly, it's probably just an F# diminished triad which is a very basic chord. This naming scheme reminds me of any Chord Identifiers on DAWs which tent to just be garbage and only approach chords from the add/no angle once it finds a small set of notes it matches to a known chord.

Comment: @teodozjan why is there a flat 8?

Comment: @SovereignSun I don't know I just found this tool. I'm not good at at chord theory

Comment: Wait... Are you saying `F#mb5` doesn't exist? I mean, it's just be a diminished triad, but is that naming convention actually wrong? I've seen, say, `F#majb5` before.

Comment: @AgustínLado: No, I said F#m7b12 doesn't make sense. F#mb5 is at least unconventional, and is normally called Fdim or Fo. Maybe you saw `F#maj7(b5)`?

Answer (score -5):

It contains F#, A, C#, F#, F#, C

Comment: Can you explain which pitch is the "b#8" and why?

Comment: Cb# = C because # means sharp and b means flat

Comment: And which one is the "b12"?

Comment: b12 is a Gb, 12 means 5

Comment: Sharps and flats don't cancel out each other.

Comment: Oh dear, Alex G-I. Not a smart Alex...If 12 means 5, then it would be C#. And since it's an **F#** chord, it certainly wouldn't be called **Gb**!!! And even if it was b12, that would make it Fnat.

Comment: Fnat looks and sounds funny (:D